# Combining Asyncio library (telethon) with Pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, telethon

I want to combine a `TelegramBot` with a `PYQT` application. I'm using `telethon` to listen to a channel and print out messages. However, this should run in the background, that is, the user should be able to interact with the GUI while the bot is listening to messages. So far, I've only managed to implement a blocking variant. That is, the gui is not showing because `with client` seems to be blocking.

```
class Win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("layout.ui", self)

        client = TelegramClient('session', TELE_ID, TELE_HASH)

        @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=["test"]))
        async def m_listener(event):
            print(event)

        with client:
               client.run_until_disconnected()
```

I also tried to move the last statement to a thread with

```
        ...
        def run():
            with client:
                client.run_until_disconnected()
        threading.Thread(target=run).start()
```

However, then I get a `There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.` error because `with client` tries to load the loop from `asyncio` which can only be done in the main thread.

Do you can give me any starting point on how to solve this?

Comment: you have to create `client` also in thead. And you may need to use `Queue` to communicate between threads.

Comment: PyQt has own class `QThread` which may work better with rest of code.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to create new async loop inside thread - so it needs to create new  Client also in thread.

```
import asyncion

def run_bot():

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    
    #client = TelegramClient('session', TELE_ID, TELE_HASH, loop=loop)
    client = TelegramClient('session', TELE_ID, TELE_HASH)  # also works

    # ... code ...

    with client:
        client.run_until_disconnected()

# --- 

threading.Thread(target=run_bot).start()
```

---

Working example which also use `Queue` (`queue_in`) to send command to `bot`.

It has also `queue_out` to send message from `bot` to `PyQt` but I didn't create code which could use this message.

`PyQt` has own class `QThread` which could be more useful because it uses `singals` to send messages.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
#from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

import os

TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')
TELE_ID, TELE_HASH = TOKEN.split(":")

# --- classes ---

class MyWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, queue_in, queue_out):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.queue_in = queue_in
        self.queue_out = queue_out
        
        self.label = QLabel(self, text='Hello World', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.button = QPushButton(self, text='Stop Bot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.stop_bot)
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.label)
        vbox.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.setLayout(vbox)

    def stop_bot(self):
        self.queue_in.put('stop')
        
# --- functions ---

def run_bot(queue_in, queue_out):
    print("run_bot()")

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    print('loop:', loop)
    
    client = TelegramClient('session', TELE_ID, TELE_HASH)#, loop=loop)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/test'))
    async def test_cmd(event):
        #print('[BOT] event:', event)
        print('[BOT] message:', event.message.message)
        queue_out.put(event.message.message)
        
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(pattern='/stop'))
    async def stop_cmd(event):
        print('[BOT] message:', event.message.message)
        queue_out.put(event.message.message)

        await client.disconnect()  # it stops client

    async def check_queue():
        print('[BOT] check_queue(): start')
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            #print('[BOT] check_queue(): check')
            if not queue_in.empty():
                cmd = queue_in.get()
                print('[BOT] check_queue(): queue_in get:', cmd)
                if cmd == 'stop':
                    await client.disconnect()
                    break

    loop.create_task(check_queue())
    
    with client:
        print('[BOT] start')
        client.run_until_disconnected()
        print('[BOT] stop')
    
# --- main ---

queue_in  = Queue()  # to send data to bot
queue_out = Queue()  # to receive data from bot 
thread = Thread(target=run_bot, args=(queue_in, queue_out))
thread.start()

# - GUI -

print('PyQt')
app = QApplication([])

win = MyWindow(queue_in, queue_out)
win.show()

app.exec()

queue_in.put('stop')
thread.join()
```